# Filling an array with changing string value

Tags: python, arrays

I want to fill an array with word suffixes while making a dictionary with their indexes.
In a loop I do the following:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    suf = s[:j]
    suff_dict.update({suf: i})
    suff_arr[i][0] = suf
    suff_arr[i][1] = 0
    j -= 1
```

The dictionary is filled right, however, the array is filled only with the 1st letter.

```
[['H', 0], ['H', 0], ['H', 0], ['H', 0], ['H', 0], ['H', 0]]
{'HELLO': 1, 'HELL': 2, 'HEL': 3, 'HE': 4, 'H': 5}
```

Could you help me to find a problem?

Comment: Your code is not complete. What is the initial value of `j`, of `suff_arr`, ...etc?

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
s='HELLO'
suff_arr=[]
suff_dict={}
for i in range(len(s)):
    suf = s[i:]
    suff_dict.update({suf: i})
    suff_arr.append(suf)
print(suff_arr, suff_dict)
```

I do not really unterstand why you would have nested lists, with a zero, but if you want that you could do it like this:

```py
s='HELLO'
suff_arr=[]
suff_dict={}
for i in range(len(s)):
    suf = s[i:]
    suff_dict.update({suf: i})
    suff_arr.append([suf,0])
print(suff_arr, suff_dict)
```

Also you said you wanted the word suffixes not prefixes, so I changed that too. If you want the prefixes, simply replace `s[i:]` with `s[:i+1]`

Answer (score 1):

Since the data in this question is unclear I can't exactly guess what you are trying to do. But from what I understand this might help u.

```
s = 'HELLO'
suff_dict = {}
j=len(s)
suff_arr = []
for i in range(len(s)):
  suf = s[:j]
  suff_dict.update({suf: i})
  suff_arr.append([suf,0])
  j -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, as the previous answers have indicated, this is a case for building your list with "append()". Here is some explanation for the unexpected results you were seeing, it has to do with how Python stores and refers to objects in memory.
Copy and run the code below, it's my attempt to show why you were getting unexpected results in your list. The "id()" function in Python returns a unique identifier for an object, and I use it to show where list values are being stored in memory.

```
print('**** Values stored directly in list. ****')
arr = [0] * 3

print('All the items in the list refer to the same memory address.')
c = 0
for item in arr:
    print(f'arr[{c}] id = ', id(item))
    c += 1
print('\n')

for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i] = i
    
print('As values are updated, new objects are created in memory:')
c = 0
for item in arr:
    print(f'arr[{c}] id = ', id(item))
    c += 1

print('And we see the results we expect:')
print(arr)

print('\n')

print('**** Values stored in sub list. ****')
arr = [[0]] * 3

print('All the items in the list refer to the same memory location.')
c = 0
for item in arr:
    print(f'arr[{c}] id = ', id(item))
    c += 1
print('\n')


for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i][0] = i

print('The same memory address is repeatedly overwritten.')
c = 0
for item in arr:
    print(f'arr[{c}] id = ', id(item))
    c += 1
print('\n')

print('And we say "Wut??"')
print(arr)
```